# checking if date is between range

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom calendar setup using a UICollectionView and I have an array that hold dates through 30 days.  What I am trying to do is find out if a value is between the current date and 7 days before it.  If it is I need it to do something.  I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  Here is what I have so far:

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy"];
    NSdate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *newCurrentDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:+14*24*60*60];
    NSDate *sevenDaysBeforeCurrent = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-7*24*60*60];




    if([[df stringFromDate:[days objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]] compare:[df stringFromDate:newCurrentDate]] == NSOrderedAscending && [[df stringFromDate:[days objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]] compare:[df stringFromDate:sevenDaysBeforeCurrent]] == NSOrderedDescending )
    {

            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dates.png"];
            [myButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
```

What it does is change the image of every date before the newCurrentDate instead of just the previous 7.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Heres the initialization of the array:

```
myDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    date = [NSDate date];




    for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
    {
        NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
        [comps setDay:i];
        [myDays addObject:[cal dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:today options:0]];
    }
```

Comment: Why are you creating strings? Why don't you just compare the dates themselves?

Comment: I had it originally [[days objectAtindex:indexPath.item] compare:date] but it would give a warning and when i would run the application would crash.

Comment: then you don't have `NSDate`s in the array.

Comment: I added the initialization of the array.  I thought this was adding them in as dates but I could be wrong.  Could that be why is having issues checking between the dates?

Comment: It should be fine, what's the error message you get from the crash log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *dateSevenDaysPrior = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(7 * 24 * 60 * 60)];
NSDate *someDate = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(3 * 24 * 60 * 60)]; // adjust as you like

if (([dateSevenDaysPrior compare:someDate] != NSOrderedDescending) &&
    ([someDate compare:currentDate] != NSOrderedDescending))
{
    NSLog(@"date is in range");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"date is not in range");
}
```

This assumes that what you're providing (what `someDate` is standing for in this example) really is an instance of NSDate.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to be using the dateFormatter.

```
if([dateInQuestion compare:newCurrentDate] == NSOrderedAscending && [dateInQuestion compare:sevenDaysBeforeCurrent] == NSOrderedDescending){
    // do something
}
```