# How to check if a date is between two dates?

Tags: objective-c

How to start date and end date comparing in iphone sdk code?

Example:->

```
if ([nowdate compare:raceStartDate] == NSOrderedDescending && [nowdate compare:raceEndDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
{  

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033769/checking-if-date-is-between-range , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250383/date-in-a-specific-range-with-nsorderedascending-and-nsordereddescending

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDate *date1;
NSDate *date2;


if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");        

} else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");

} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
- (BOOL)date:(NSDate*)nowdate isBetweenDate:(NSDate*)raceStartDate andDate:(NSDate*)raceEndDate
{
    if ([nowdate compare:raceStartDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
        return NO;

    if ([nowdate compare:raceEndDate] == NSOrderedDescending) 
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```